# Cleartool command to list all files part of a changeset

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool

I have a requirement where I want to use Cleartool and
1. I would like to pass a chageset number to Clearcase server and would like to see all files that would be part of that Changeset
2. Pass these file names to Clearcase server and copy the latest version of the files onto my local machine.

Is there a way to achieve this functionality using cleartool?

Can someone please suggest the commands with the necessary parameters that needs to be passed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

With ClearCase UCM, the "changeset" is part of an UCM activity

To see the content (ie the list of versions modified) in an activity, you can do a:

```
cleartool descr -l activity:myActivity@\myPvob
```

If the **naming convention** for your activities names is a "number", then "myActivity" would be "aNumber".

For getting the latest version, it is best to:

- know what Stream that activity has been created (through fmt_ccase):

  ```
  cleartool descr -fmt "%[stream]Xp" activity:myActivity@\myPVob
  ```
- and then modify the config spec of a dynamic view

  ```
  element * .../myStream/LATEST
  ```

Comment: Hi, When I run the descr command from cleartool by providing the Activity name, it does show some properties of the Activity and finally throws an error which states "Cannot get view info for current view: not a ClearCase object" . Can you please suggest what might be wrong.

Comment: @user2732988 yes, simply execute that same command in a view: `cd m:\aDynamicView`, `cleartool descr -l activity:anActivity@\aPVob` (assuming you are on Windows here).

Comment: Hi VonC..works perfect...but is there a way to execute these commands from a client machine..i am thinking of installing ccrccli on the client...would the same command work then?

Comment: @user2732988 it would if you execute them from a view: for CCRC 7.x, a web view (a sort of snapshot view on your disk). From CCRC 8.x, a dynamic view can work too (dynamic view are now supported with ClearTeam 8.x)