# Clearcase: Activity branch information

Tags: clearcase

Is there any command which will display all the information associated with a particular activity branch. Like:

- On which label it was created?
- On which label currently it is?
- What are the files are checked in the branch. What are there latest versions?
- Who created this branch?

Is there any single command for all those which will display these information (not in graphical view)

Answer (score 1):

The only two commands are:

- [`cleartool lsact`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsactivity.htm)
- [cleartool descr -l activity:anActivity@/apvob](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_describe.htm)

You can get that way the list of versions for each file.
See also "[Cleartool command to list all files part of a changeset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18533995/6309)"

You can combine the second command (`descr`) with a [`-fmt` (`fmt_ccase`) directive](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm) in order to get other [activity attributes](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm#ref_fmtccase_refsect2_35782__ref_fmtccase_table_36209), like its associated view (from which you can deduce the stream)

But that won't give you from which label the activity started. For that, you can [list the foundation baseline of the stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4440593/6309).

And that won't give you "On which label currently it is?": the activity list versions. The fact that those versions are or are not labelled is not relevant for the activity. You would need to describe the version in order to see if it has a label attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

If this is UCM, and by "activity branch" you mean the stream it is on, you can get the information about the stream by using cleartool lsstream -long -cview while in the view in question. The output will look something like this:

```
stream "brian_testrep1_2"
  2017-08-17T17:50:15-04:00 by Brian.None@DESKTOP-LQ0QA86
  owner: DESKTOP-LQ0QA86\Brian
  group: DESKTOP-LQ0QA86\None
  project: testrep1@\testproject (development stream)
  default deliver stream: testrep1_Int@\testproject
  development streams:
  contains activities:
  foundation baselines:
    test_2@\testproject (testcomp1@\testproject) (modifiable)
  recommended baselines:
  views:
    Brian_testrep1_2
  policies:
  ...
```